# Is it possible to use a dead 9V battery as a 5V power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I couldn’t find anything about this online. Will a dead 9V battery (let’s say around 5.5V) act as a healthy 5V supply? Or will it deliver too little current?

Comment: Supply for how much current? How dead is dead in "can supply this and that voltage under this and that current"? Inanswerable without these two key facts, trivial to answer with. Hence: not really a question.

Comment: Marcus. When I say 'little' current, I am talking in comparison to the average current a healthy 9V battery delivers. 'Dead' refers to a 9V battery that has dropped to about 5V. The question is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Could you put that clarification into your question?  The question is only as straightforward as the definition of a "dead battery", and trust me, that's not a straightforward definition.

Comment: Do you mean "dropped to 5V" in that the battery, under load, delivers 5V?  Or do you mean that the battery in open circuit reads 5V on a good multimeter?

Comment: a healthy 9 V battery already delivers little current

Comment: A 'dead' 9V battery as in a 9V battery that has been used to the point the where the voltage across it becomes around 5V.

Comment: Here is a straightforward answer:  no.

Comment: @MahmoudMaarouf, how can you possibly expect a useful answer when you never defined what is a `healthy 5V supply`?

Comment: The older MSP430x3xx series would run from about 2.5 V to about 5.5 V or so. They'd chew away slowly on maybe 10 uA draw. Might work for a while. They certainly worked on a potato or lemon battery. ;)

Comment: Add these to the question and you have a chance of getting far better responses:  How accurate does the 5V need to be? (4.9-5.1, 5V-6V, ...?), how much current? (10 UA, 100 uA, 1 mA, 10 mA, ...), operate for how long? (1 minute hour day week, ...?) , ... . **BUT** generally a 9V ALKALINE or Zinc based primary battery has 6 internal cells. These start at 1.65V (more like 1.5V for Zinc Cl etc) , are essentially dead at 1V/cell, very dead at 0.9V/cell and MAY provide uAs to maybe 10's of uAs for a small while at 0.8V/cell. SO 6 x 1V/cell = 6V. 6 x 0.9 = 5.4 V/cell, 6 x 0.8 = 4.8V/cell. ...

Comment: @jsotola For example, a 5V healthy supply in that it can deliver decent levels of current (in comparison to other alkaline batteries) for a long period of time (about life expectancy of AA or AAA batteries)

Comment: @MahmoudMaarouf, that makes your question ridiculous ... a 9 V battery consists of six AAAA cells ... it cannot provide that level of current when it is new

Comment: I have found inside the 9v battery, even "completely dead", that some of the cells have some life left (using a Joule-Thief, for instance), and other cells may actually be charged negatively (making them act like a capacitor and pass no more current, hence the dead cell).

Answer (score 6):

A healthy battery has low ESR to support  %V drop / %rise of I = ESR [Ohms]

A dead battery has its charge capacity Q=CV with in Farads now reduced < 1% to < 10% of initial charge.

At the same time, dead batteries ESR rises >>10x the initial value.

A stable supply is often defined by a 10% V tolerance for some rated max current which also defines the Load Regulation error now in terms of ESR.

So if your "circuit has minimal current load, it can work, but is it reliable, alive, suitable?

**No**. It is called "dead" for a reason. But if it works for you, with no significant load except logic levels, play with it.  But this is not how Engineers specify performance. ;)it just worked)

Engineered power supplies have (at least) guaranteed specs for mAh Vmin:max  or Vnom, % tolerance error and load % V regulation error.

This has no specs. so you decide.

Answer (score 2):

> Will a dead 9V battery (let’s say around 5.5V) act as a healthy 5V supply? Or will it deliver too little current?

To use a 9V battery at around 5.5V, which is its "almost completely dead" point, you need a large parallel filter capacitot to minimise its effective impedance and to maximise its ability to provide even minor current peaks. A 100 uF cap may allow a rice pudding to be powered for a while. A 1000 uF would be better and more may not hurt. Even then, see below:

[HERE](https://www.google.com/search?q=9v+battery+voltage+chart&tbm=isch&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwji7dGH-vXmAhXF2nMBHXktBTkQrNwCegQIARA0&biw=1222&bih=615) are zillions of curves and related web pages that will allow you to investigate a solution once you have answered some important questions.

[Here](https://www.powerstream.com/9V-Alkaline-tests.htm) is one example from that list that provides some escellent example and which shows the wide variations between some typical cells. The Nuon NU cell in those tests is impressive.

For us to answer your question better you need to address these points (at least):

- How accurate does the 5V need to be? (4.9-5.1, 5V-6V, ...?),
- How much current? (10 UA, 100 uA, 1 mA, 10 mA, ...),
- Operate for how long? (1 minute hour day week, ...?)
- Brand & model of battery. This can make a VAST difference.

  - Temperature - relevant at extremes
- Datasheets where possible.

**BUT**

Typically a 9V ALKALINE or Zinc based primary battery has 6 internal cells.
These start at 1.65V (more like 1.5V for Zinc Chloride, "Heavy duty" etc), are

essentially dead at 1V/cell,
very dead at 0.9V/cell and
MAY provide uAs to maybe 10's of uAs for a small while at 0.8V/cell.

SO

6 x 1V/cell = 6V.
6 x 0.9 = 5.4 V/cell
6 x 0.8 = 4.8V/cell.

At 5.5V you are typically in "very dead" territory.

---

[This page](http://elfintechnologies.com/BattBoost.html)  shows the use of a boost converter to get extract maximum energy.